# MySQL atomic sequence number generator

Tags: mysql, c

My program require to generate UNIQUE transaction Id through MySQL due to multiple machine environment.

I using the following MySQL function, I google review it is not atomic as I think it is.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`` FUNCTION `getNextTXID`(dummy INT) RETURNS int(11)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

DECLARE txid bigint(20);

SET txid = (SELECT next_txid FROM txid_seq LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE);

IF txid > 15000000 THEN
    SET txid = 0;
END IF;

UPDATE txid_seq SET next_txid = txid + 500 LIMIT 1;

RETURN txid;

END
```

I previously using `last_insert_id`, but a new requirement to reset after 15M number was imposed. I cannot reproduce a race condition any 2 of 100 Processes actually get the same transaction number (in a batch of 500, if application used up all 500, get again).

Question:

1. Does this function atomic
2. Any other way of doing it correctly?

Table          : `MyISAM`
Storage Engine : `MyISAM`
Auto commit    : `TRUE`

Edit:
I am using MySQL C API.
Thanks in advance for any apply.

Comment: Why is your function marked as `DETERMINISTIC`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not atomic, because you're reading and writing separately. But this should do the same operation atomically, while still returning the value from `LAST_INSERT_ID()`:

```
UPDATE txid_seq SET next_txid = LAST_INSERT_ID((next_txid * (next_txid <= 15000000)) + 500) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Seem workable, will mark as answer after I did some more testing. Thanks a tons, shmosel